# Quantiles of comonotone sums

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space. Let $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)^T$ be a random vector and $U \sim \mathrm{uniform}(0, 1)$ be a random variable, both defined on $\Omega$. We say that $\mathbf{X}$ is comonotone if $\mathbf{X} \stackrel{d}= (F_{X_1}^{-1}(U), \ldots, F_{X_n}^{-1}(U))^T$, where, for a random variable $X$, we define $F_X^{-1}(p) := \inf\{x \in \mathbb R; F_X(x) \ge p\}$, $p \in [0, 1]$. Furthermore, define $F_X^{-1+}(p) := \sup\{x \in \mathbb R; F_X(x) \le p\}$, $p \in [0, 1]$. Set $S := \sum_{i = 1}^n F_{X_i}^{-1}(U)$.

Now, suppose that $\mathbf{X}$ is comonotone. Then, for any $p \in [0, 1]$:

1. $F_S^{-1}(p) = \sum_{i = 1}^n F_{X_i}^{-1}(p)$ and
2. $F_S^{-1+}(p) = \sum_{i = 1}^n F_{X_i}^{-1+}(p)$.

How can I prove both statements? Thank you for any help!